# Software to simulate nonlinear-optics

Tags: gratis, simulation, scientific-computing

I'm a student, and I would to make a simulation of nonlinear-optic effect (like the Kerr effect). I would like a freeware who is able to produce a picture output, and manage if possible non-linear optics, it can be a demonstration soft but in this case it must be long enough.
Is there any software that can make these simulations?

Comment: Could you specify your needs and requirements for such software? ie What is your budget? What kind of output would be acceptable - data, animated pictures? Are you looking for some demonstration software or for some ray-tracer able to handle nonlinear-optics?

Comment: I would like a freeware who is able to produce a picture output, and manage if possible non-linear optics, it can be a demonstration soft but in this case it must be long enough. But I'm not sure that such software exist

Comment: Existence isn't a problem, often an answer exists than OP wouldn't even suspect. Please edit your question accordingly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This was made possible by [2003](http://wscg.zcu.cz/wscg2003/Papers_2003/H31.pdf) [studies](https://www.google.fr/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CDcQFjAC&url=http%3A%2F%2Fadsabs.harvard.edu%2Fabs%2F2003SPIE.5009..277S&ei=Wgx5U7y6D6Kg0QX2wYHoAg&usg=AFQjCNGp1JqIqp96vHFM2WpaAGrGZYzFkg&bvm=bv.66917471,d.d2k). The first paper includes some pictures. I couldn't find an avaible piece of software making use of this.

The relevant algorithm seems to be [SMARDDA](http://oposite.stsci.edu/pubinfo/pr/1999/30/index.html). Havn't found any graphic/publicly avaible implementation, so to my (informed) opinion this question has today no relevant answer. I'ld love to be proved wrong.

Comment: This answer would be more acceptable on somewhere like computational science SE. HEre we are only concerned with actual implemented software. I think this is more fitting as a comment than an answer.

Comment: @Oxinabox As he is stating he couldn't find any available actually developed software options I'd say talking about research that may help him is the good.

Comment: We had discussed this on meta, and "answers that show no answer exists are OK".